# Is it possible to add graphics card to Toshiba L-300 model Laptop

Tags: laptop, graphics-card

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can a graphics card (Nvidia) be added to a laptop?](https://superuser.com/questions/120767/can-a-graphics-card-nvidia-be-added-to-a-laptop)
>   [external video card for notebook?](https://superuser.com/questions/139734/external-video-card-for-notebook)

Is it possible to add graphics card to Toshiba L-300 model Laptop?
Are there any **external graphics card** available? 
How to install them?
Whether any of them are available in India?

Comment: just to get you started they have had PCI and PCI-E docking things that were capable of hooking to laptops. . http://www.villageinstruments.com/tiki-index.php?page=ViDock this is just an example of one of them, and NOT a recommendation. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dh5wDT5t9uE and a video, notice how it did Not work on some things.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can a graphics card (Nvidia) be added to a laptop?](http://superuser.com/questions/120767/can-a-graphics-card-nvidia-be-added-to-a-laptop) also see [external video card for notebook?](http://superuser.com/questions/139734/external-video-card-for-notebook)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laptop computers are harder to install components in than the desktop equivalents. A graphics card can be installed in a Toshiba laptop, but `you need to completely disassemble the laptop.` The graphics card is located under the motherboard; therefore you need to remove most of the laptop components to access the card. Be sure to touch any non-painted metal that is connected to ground to avoid harming your computer with an electrostatic discharge.

Follow these links for more information:
http://techtips.salon.com/install-graphics-card-toshiba-laptop-2834.html

Yes some cards available for notebook pc, but I am not confirm about their cost and availability. 
Visit this http://www.villagetronic.com/vidock2/index.html

As I have seen your configuration of your laptop it is not good for high end games. But you can use/ try this if you want to upgrade this one.