# How to get a triple monitor setup for my Vaio?

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, pcmcia

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [External video card for notebook?](https://superuser.com/questions/139734/external-video-card-for-notebook)

I'm trying to get a triple monitor setup for my Windows 7 Vaio PCG-3112L, so I think I need a PCMCIA video card. I'm having a bit of trouble finding one, though. Do you have any recommendations for good models?

Also, I'm not sure in general what to look for when getting a video card.

(Do I want to be looking for an ExpressCard instead of PCMCIA card? Will they fit in the same laptop slots?)

Comment: What laptop do you have? What kind of slots does it have? (You need to be as exact as possible. There are many subtle variations.)

Comment: ExpressCards use internal USB 2.0 or PCI-Ex1 connection while PCMCIA cards use their own bus system which is similar to PCI. Anyway, they are incompatible and I think that PCMCIA doesn't offer any advantages over say USB video cards (unless you happen not to have a USB port). There are some external ExpressCars video cards, but they too are a bit rare and unusual.

Comment: As noted, USB video adapters are common.  Here are some examples http://www.startech.com/AV/USB-Video-Adapters.  Also as noted, more info on your hardware will give better answers.

Comment: I added my laptop model to the OP. Will a video adapter work, or do I need another video card? I can't just plug another monitor into my HDMI port and get three unique displays, right?